# Credit Card Number Sensor Challenge

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I am trying to write a program that sensors the first 12 digits of a 'credit card number' and then prints it with the last 4 digits still there. (4444444444444444=************4444). I am having a problem making the loop stop at just the first 12 digits. The output is always 12 *'s. Here is the code:

```
credit=""
while len(credit)<16 or len(credit)>16:
        credit=input("Please input credit card number: ")
x=1
k="*"
while x<12:
    for ele in credit:
        if ele.isdigit() and x<12:
            credit=credit.replace(ele, k)
            x=x+1
print(credit)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the *re* module you could this.

First of all ensure that the input is exactly 16 characters and is comprised entirely of digits.

Then print 12 asterisks (constant) followed by the last 4 characters of the input which can be achieved with traditional slicing.

```
while len(ccn := input('Please input credit card number: ')) != 16 or not ccn.isdigit():
    print('Must be 16 digits. Try again')

print('*'*12, ccn[-4:], sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
print(re.sub('\d{12}', '*'*12, credit))
```

Comment: While this works, it doesn't really answer the OP's question, nor does it give any insight into how it functions.